Redirect outgoing VPN traffic on specific port to localhost on macOS
I want to redirect all traffic that would normally go to a specific TCP port on remotehost (that I can reach via openvpn) instead to localhost, where I have ssh forwarding listening on that port. I try it with these setup:
On remotehost for testing:
nc -l -p 12345 -k -v

On MacBook:
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1  # should not be needed
echo 'rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port 12345 -> 127.0.0.1 port 12345
pass out route-to (lo0 127.0.0.1) proto tcp from any to any port 12345' | sudo pfctl -e -f -
ssh -4 -L 12345:127.0.0.1:12345 remotehost

On MacBook test:
echo foo | nc -v remotehost 12345

The idea is that I can "fake" on the MacBook that I can reach remotehost on TCP port 12345, when in reality it has only SSH port 22 open.
The above commands work when remotehost is e.g. a publicly available Linux server, but it does not work when it is a Linux server that can only be reached via openvpn. It must have something to do with precedence of route table over PF, as when I add this entry:
sudo route add -net <remotehost>/32 -iface lo0

The PF redirection suddenly works, but not anymore the SSH tunnel traffic.
I tried to reproduce this with FreeBSD, but to my surprise there both worked flawlessly, VPN or not, so the problem must be macOS specific.
Does anybody have an idea how I could achieve this with macOS as well? Somehow the route table entry that openvpn adds circumvents the pfctl rule.
I have found these links that seem to deal with related issues, but did not help me:

https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/issues/102
https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/issues/563
https://serverfault.com/questions/564478/routing-table-vs-pf-precendence
https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/

